# Need to batch rename files with names from text file using core utils

Tags: shell-script, rhel, rename

So I am a bit of a noob and have a problem at work. There is a program outputs names in a ie

```
apple
banana
orange
P1n34ppl3
```

The problem is that the files that correspond to that (separate program) are just in 1.txt 2.txt and so on. Is there a way to iterate through the files in a given directory renaming them to the names in the text file using just the core utils ie mv, ls, grep, awk, sed. The system is a standalone RHEL box that is kind of old and no way to get patches or connect to repos with new programs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried and where is it not working? It's fine to ask for help but it's also important to give an effort.

Comment: The task you want to accomplish should be feasible with standard tools, but it's not clear what precisely you want to achieve. You seem to say that 1.txt should be renamed to *apple*, 2.txt to *banana* and so on. Is that correct? If so, loop over the output of the program and count the text files, e.g. `i=1; for file in $(program); do mv $i.txt $file; i=$((i+1)); done`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are as many non-hidden files in the current working directory as there are lines in the output of `your-program` and that none of the names of the files contain newline characters, you could do in a shell with support for ksh-style process substitution (ksh, zsh, bash):

```
paste -d '\n' <(ls -v) <(your-program) | xargs -rn2 -d '\n' echo mv --
```

(and remove the `echo` if that looks OK).

`ls` with `-v` sorts numerically so that for instance `10.txt` comes between `9.txt` and `11.txt` instead of between `1.txt` and `2.txt` with the normal lexical order.

`paste` zips the lines of `ls` and those of `your-program`.

`xargs` gets two lines at a time to pass to `mv`.

`-v`, `-r`, `-d` are GNU extensions, but your system should have GNU utilities.

If you have `zsh`, you can do it a lot more reliably with:

```
files=( *(Nn) ) # or *.txt(Nn) or <->.txt(Nn) for number.txt only
lines=( ${(f)"$(your-program)"} )
for old new (${files:^lines}) echo mv -- $old $new
```